# Meaning of Homogeneity in matrix theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

What does the sentence  "The Jacobson radical in matrix ring is homogeneous." mean? Is it a true or false statement?

Any way, what does "homogeneous" mean in regard of  matrix theory?

Any answer or introducing a reference is appreciated!

Comment: This is not specific for matrix theory.

Answer (score 0):

An ideal $I$ of an associative S-graded ring $R$ is called *homogeneous* if 
$$
I=\bigoplus_{s\in S}I_s,
$$
where $I=I\cap R_S$, and $R=\oplus_{s\in S}R_s$ is the grading, with $R_sR_t\subseteq R_{st}$. In this sense, we use "homogeneous" for the Jacobson radical, see [here](http://ac.els-cdn.com/S002186939690397X/1-s2.0-S002186939690397X-main.pdf?_tid=b8e301e6-9bb5-11e7-b4c8-00000aab0f01&acdnat=1505659225_adecf01b4bb099c86dfa269bf151b21d).